# Spring PetClinic application showing error in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have imported the Spring PetClinic application but it is showing error in pom.xml. I have force updated Maven but still the problem persists. The error is as follows:-

Failed to execute goal on project spring-petclinic: Could not resolve dependencies 
    for project org.springframework.samples:spring-petclinic:jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: 
    Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
    -> org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE (ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-
    maven-plugin:1.8.0:run:default:generate-resources)

The pom.xml is given below. The error is shown in the execution tag under groupId ro.isdc.wro4j.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-petclinic</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <name>petclinic</name>

  <properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
    <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>

    <jacoco.version>0.8.2</jacoco.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Spring Boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Databases - Uses HSQL by default -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of webjars -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information
              if a META-INF/build-info.properties file is present -->
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <additionalProperties>
                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
              </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information if a git.properties
        file is present at the classpath -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</dateFormat>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
          </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
          <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
          <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
          <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
          <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
          <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>    
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @TomazFernandes  I have posted the pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

In case, someone is facing issue with wro4j for PetClinic application.

Change wro4j version to 1.9.0, it works for openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16

`<wro4j.version>1.9.0</wro4j.version>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong version in you Spring-boot parent dependency. You should use 2.0.6-RELEASE, or any other RELEASE version.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry it didn't resolve the issue. Now the following error is shown -  Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework.samples:spring-petclinic:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6-RELEASE

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on my first answer, I hoped I had edited it fast enough. There is no “-“ in the version, it’s a “.” instead. 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: The previous error is gone but some new error have come up during compilation. Exception occured while processing: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Could not compile less. 24 error(s) occurred

Comment: Can you provide more details on the exception? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, but are the errors related to the LESS compiling? Is it an error in your less files? I can’t really tell without more info. Peharps you should post another question with this error, since the original error was successfully corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Which Java-Version do you use?

When building Spring petclinic on Java 9 or higher, problems with wroj have been reported https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j/pull/1041 .

These problems are solved in the code of wroj after version 1.8.0 https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j , but no version with this solution has been released https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j/branches .

So you have to build wroj version 1.8.1-SNAPSHOT yourself and use this version to build petclinic framework-version on Java 9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this issue by simply run the below command from terminal/command prompt:
mvn spring-javaformat:apply